# How to call a function of class from a different class using reflection in JAVA?

Tags: java, reflection

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils;
public class subscriber
{
    public calculator cal=new calculator();
    String funcName = "";
    int result;
    public void getValues(String strfuncName)
    {
            funcName= strfuncName; //has the function name of class calculator

    }

    public void giveResult()
    {
            result=cal.funcName();
     //i want it to call the function whose name is stored in funcName
    }
}
```

How do i do this using the reflection and 
importing **org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils**

And as the function call can be dynamic that is any of the function can be called I cannot predefine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("Methodname", new Class[] {});
String output = (String) method.invoke(obj, new Object[] {}); // String return type here, Sorry i mean yourType is your return type..
```

Comment: What is obj and Yourtype here.. As when I type YourType it is not recognizing it..

Comment: @IndiraChoudhary obj is class instance. YourType is return type of your method i.e typecast .

Comment: is it a keyword? Coz the **YourType** is not being accepted in eclipse..!

Comment: Its not a keyword i mean yourType is your return type.. I have edited my code.

Comment: i used your code.. and it is showing only one error now..i.e.
i used
    Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(strInterfaceName, new Class[] {});
strInterfaceName has the name of method to be invoked..
error is being displayed that...
**strInterfaceName cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: obj.getClass().getMethod("strInterfaceName", new Class[] {}); -- Method name give in double quotes.. first argument getMethod is string type

Comment: I tried giving it in quotes..
it is throwing an error that
Default Constructor cannot handle exception type NoSuchMethodException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor **for the first line of code** (define it where?)

Comment: Surround invoke and getmethod block with Try catch  and if your method is accepting any argument specify its argument type in second argument of getmethod. when invoking that method give the respective value in invoke method as second argument. like method = insatnce.getClass().getMethod("CallMethod", String.class); String output = (String) method.invoke(insatnce, new String(""));

Comment: thanks a looooooootttt @LDay ...:)
You really helped me a lott !
Thank you..!

Comment: is it possible to make a call without creating the object?

Comment: To my knowledge we cant invoke method without object instance unless it is static method or from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

From my [blog](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html)

```
/**
 * If it exists, invoke methodName on receiver - passing
 * parameters (if they exist) as arguments. If
 * receiver.methodName(parameters) returns, return the
 * returned value.
 * 
 * @param receiver
 *          The receiver to invoke.
 * @param methodName
 *          The name of the method to call.
 * @param parameters
 *          The arguments to pass to the method.
 * @return The value returned from invoking methodName on
 *         receiver.
 * @throws Exception
 *           Any Exception thrown by invoking the method
 *           with the passed parameters.
 */
public static Object callMethod(Object receiver,
    String methodName, Object... parameters)
    throws Exception {
  if (receiver == null || methodName == null) {
    return null;
  }
  methodName = methodName.trim();
  if (methodName.length() == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  Class<?> cls = receiver.getClass();
  Method toInvoke = null;
  outer: for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
    if (!methodName.equals(method.getName())) {
      continue;
    }
    Class<?>[] mTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    if (parameters == null && mTypes == null) {
      toInvoke = method;
      break;
    } else if (safeSize(mTypes) == 0
        || safeSize(parameters) == 0) {
      continue;
    } else if (safeSize(mTypes) != safeSize(parameters)) {
      continue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mTypes.length; ++i) {
      if (!mTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(parameters[i]
          .getClass())) {
        continue outer;
      }
    }
    toInvoke = method;
    break;
  }
  if (toInvoke != null) {
    try {
      return toInvoke.invoke(receiver, parameters);
    } catch (Exception t) {
      throw t;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

/**
 * Returns the size (or length) of an array.
 * 
 * @param obj
 *          The Array to find the size of .
 * @return The length of the array (if object is an
 *         array), or 0.
 */
private static int safeSize(Object obj) {
  if (obj != null) {
    return Array.getLength(obj);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering If you could help me.. what is the **safeSize** that you have used above in the code?

Comment: @IndiraChoudhary Edited to provide `safeSize`.

Comment: Frisch
is your solution possible.. if i do not want to create the object of the class? in the current class and the call should be all dynamically if i send the package through string?

Comment: You mean invoke a static method by class name? I may be able to add that, but it doesn't currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can give something like this :

```
 public class subscriber
    {
        public calculator cal=new calculator();
        java.lang.reflect.Method funcName;
        int result;
        public void getValues(java.lang.reflect.Method strfuncName)
        {
                funcName= strfuncName; //has the function name of class calculator

        }

        public void giveResult()
        {
                result= method.invoke(cal, arg1, arg2,...);

        }
    }
```

And Somewhere You can get method , and pass method like this :

```
     subscriber sub=new subscriber();
     java.lang.reflect.Method method;

        try {
          method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
          sub.getValues(method);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
          // ...
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
          // ...
        }
```

he parameters identify the very specific method you need (if there are several overloaded available, if the method has no arguments, only give methodName).

Read about [Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: Nope Sujith. i cannot go the way you have stated.. It has to be in the **subscriber** class only..!
The call should be from **subscriber** class... and value returned to the **subscriber** class..

Comment: Where you will call getValues() method ?

Comment: its a three class combo.. class adapt calls subscriber...and subscriber calls calculator..calculator returns the value..and the flow goes vice versa then

Comment: Ok. where ever you want to call getValues() method, you can use, " method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);  "  and can pass "method" variable ass argument to the same function .